# How to fix Unclosed quotation mark in powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, powershell-3.0

There is a particular email address that look like this in my csv file

```
"WZM","WZMDSDF","Kevin.O'Neil@gmail.com","True","mb"
```

I'm inserting it like this to my sql database using like this

```
 $queryII = "insert into Hold_Inv (Hold,GID,Source,Type,CreatedDate) VALUES ('$($item.Hold)','$($item.GID)','$($item.Source)','$($item.Type)','$CurDate')"
```

I'm getting this error so just wondering how can I fix this unclosed quotation mark

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd : Incorrect syntax near 'Neil@gmail'.
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')
```

I have other emails in the same csv file like this jonathan.sparkle@gmail.com but I have no issue. Any help or suggestion on how to fix above error will be really appreciated

Comment: I think [`-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps#example-3--invoke-a-script-and-pass-in-variable-values-from-a-string) also auto escapes for you

Comment: In short: Programmatically double any `'` chars,. inside the expanded values, along the lines of `"... $($item.Email -replace "'", "''") ..."`

Comment: also, you might want to reconsider and use a safer alternative. see https://powershellstation.com/2016/01/05/invoke-sqlcmd-considered-harmful/